# integrating tiles in spring3, getting java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PATCH exception

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

Let me know how to initialize tiles from dispatcher and application context and if any changes required in web.xml,
this is my tiles.xml

```
<definition name="contact" extends="mainLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/contact.jsp" />
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

in application context i have used

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
    </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
    <property name="viewClass"  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

and dispatcher looks like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
```

indexController</prop>-->
                newController

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
   <property name="definitions">
     <list>
       <value>WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>

       <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="viewResolver">  
<property name="viewClass">  
<value>  
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView  
</value>  
 </property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dispatcher-Servlet

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In web.xml use this code

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.simple.SimpleTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

rest is not required for spring-tiles application, tiles.xml is depended on your requirement